# Form's data can not post (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

i am working on Codigniter,i have a issue with posting form's data..
in my form,there is different section,i have put array for that different section

**Here is my code (Controller)**

```
        <?php
        class Resume extends CI_Controller{
        var $user_id;
        function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->load->model("Resume_model");
        if($this->session->userdata('user_id') == NULL){
            redirect('user/login','refresh');
        }
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->Resume();
    }
    public function Resume(){

        if($this->input->post('Skills')){
            $Resume = $this->input->post();
            $ResumeInsert=array();
            $ResumeUpdate=array();
            $Key_Resume__ExistIDs=array();

                foreach($this->input->post('Person_id') as $key =>$value ){
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['updated'] = Date("Y-m-d");
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Importance_JK'] = $Resume['Importance_JK'];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['user_FK'] = $user_id;
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Person_id'] = $Resume['Person_id'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['email_contact'] = $Resume['email_contact'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Contact_Phone'] = $Resume['Contact_Phone'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['communication'] = $Resume['communication'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['creativity'] = $Resume['creativity'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['team_work'] = $Resume['team_work'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['organizational'] = $Resume['organizational'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Leadership'] = $Resume['Leadership'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Productivity'] = $Resume['Productivity'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Postal_Address'] = $Resume['Postal_Address'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Career_objective'] = $Resume['Career_objective'][$key];

                }

            foreach($this->input->post('emp_id') as $key =>$value ){
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_keyid'] = $Resume['emp_id'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['employer_name'] = $Resume['employer_name'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['start_Date'] = $Resume['start_Date'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['end_date'] = $Resume['end_date'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['type_id'] = $Resume['type_id'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['position'] = $Resume['position'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['responsibility'] = $Resume['responsibility'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Skills'] = $Resume['Skills'][$key];
                    print_r ($ResumeInsert);exit;
            }

            foreach($this->input->post('resume_id1') as $key =>$value ){
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['edu_id'] = $Resume['resume_id1'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['year_gain'] = $Resume['year_gain'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['qualification_name'] = $Resume['qualification_name'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['institution_name'] = $Resume['institution_name'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['outstanding_Ach'] = $Resume['outstanding_Ach'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['aquired_skill'] = $Resume['aquired_skill'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['expiry'] = $Resume['expiry'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_of_Skill'] = $Resume['Application_of_Skill'][$key];

                }
            foreach($this->input->post('resume_id2') as $key =>$value ){
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_skillID'] = $Resume['resume_id2'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['skill_name'] = $Resume['skill_name'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Licences_permits'] = $Resume['Licences_permits'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['date_Achived'] = $Resume['date_Achived'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['expiry_renewal'] = $Resume['expiry'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['skill_work'] = $Resume['application_of_skill'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['course_tilte'] = $Resume['course_tilte'][$key];

                }

            foreach($this->input->post('resume_id3') as $key =>$value ){

                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['hobbyId'] = $Resume['resume_id3'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['hobby_name'] = $Resume['hobby_name'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['achievement_name'] = $Resume['achievement_name'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_OF_hobby_work'] = $Resume['Application_of_Skill'][$key];

                }

                foreach($this->input->post('resume_id4') as $key =>$value ){

                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['ref_resume_ID'] = $Resume['resume_id4'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['referee_name'] = $Resume['referee_name'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Position_referee'] = $Resume['Position'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['company_name_ref'] = $Resume['company_name'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['phone_ref'] = $Resume['phone_ref'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['contact_email_ref'] = $Resume['contact_email'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['reference_Type'] = $Resume['reference_Type'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_of_Skill_ref'] = $Resume['Application_of_Skill'][$key];

                }

                foreach($this->input->post('resume_id5') as $key =>$value ){

                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_Id'] = $Resume['resume_id5'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_date_sent'] = $Resume['date_sent'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_busisness_name'] = $Resume['app_busisness_name'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_address'] = $Resume['app_address'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_contact_phone'] = $Resume['app_contact_phone'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_outcome'] = $Resume['app_outcome'][$key];
                    $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_date_closed'] = $Resume['app_date_closed'][$key];

                }
                       if(isset($Resume['id'][$key]))
                       {
                        // echo "test";exit;
                        $Key_Resume__ExistIDs[]=$Resume['id'][$key];
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Person_id'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Person_id'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Person_id'];
                        }
                           if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['email_contact'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['email_contact'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['email_contact'];
                        }
                           if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Contact_Phone'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Contact_Phone'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Contact_Phone'];
                        }
                           if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['communication'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['communication'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['communication'];
                        }
                           if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['creativity'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['creativity'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['creativity'];
                        }
                           if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['team_work'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['team_work'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['team_work'];
                        }
                           if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['organizational'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['organizational'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['organizational'];
                        }
                           if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Leadership'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Leadership'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Leadership'];
                        }
                           if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Productivity'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Productivity'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Productivity'];
                        }
                           if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Postal_Address'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Postal_Address'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Postal_Address'];
                        }

                           if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Career_objective'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Career_objective'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Career_objective'];
                        }


                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_keyid'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['resume_keyid'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_keyid'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['employer_name'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['employer_name'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['employer_name'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['start_Date'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['start_Date'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['start_Date'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['end_date'] != "") {
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['end_date'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['end_date'];
                       }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['type_id'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['type_id'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['type_id'];
                      }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['position'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['position'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['position'];
                     }

                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['edu_id'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['edu_id'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['edu_id'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['year_gain'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['year_gain'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['year_gain'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['qualification_name'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['qualification_name'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['qualification_name'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['institution_name'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['institution_name'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['institution_name'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['outstanding_Ach'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['outstanding_Ach']= $ResumeInsert[$key]['outstanding_Ach'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['aquired_skill'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['aquired_skill'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['aquired_skill'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['expiry'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['expiry'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['expiry'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_of_Skill'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Application_of_Skill'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_of_Skill'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_skillID'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['resume_skillID'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_skillID'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['skill_name'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['skill_name'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['skill_name'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Licences_permits'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Licences_permits'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Licences_permits'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['date_Achived'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['date_Achived'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['date_Achived'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['expiry_renewal'] !="") {
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['expiry_renewal'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['expiry_renewal'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['skill_work'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['skill_work'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['skill_work'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['course_tilte'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['course_tilte'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['course_tilte'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['hobbyId'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['hobbyId'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['hobbyId'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['hobby_name'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['hobby_name'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['hobby_name'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['achievement_name'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['achievement_name'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['achievement_name'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_OF_hobby_work'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Application_OF_hobby_work'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_OF_hobby_work'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['ref_resume_ID'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['ref_resume_ID'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['ref_resume_ID'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['referee_name'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['referee_name'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['referee_name'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Position_referee'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Position_referee'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Position_referee'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['company_name_ref'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['company_name_ref'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['company_name_ref'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['phone_ref'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['phone_ref'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['phone_ref'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['contact_email_ref'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['contact_email_ref'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['contact_email_ref'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['reference_Type'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['reference_Type'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['reference_Type'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_of_Skill_ref'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Application_of_Skill_ref'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_of_Skill_ref'];
                        }
                        if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_date_sent'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['app_date_sent'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_date_sent'];
                        }
                         if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_Id'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['Application_Id'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['Application_Id'];
                         }
                         if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_busisness_name'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['app_busisness_name'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_busisness_name'];
                         }
                         if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_address'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['app_address'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_address'];
                         }
                         if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_contact_phone'] != "")
                           {
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['app_contact_phone'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_contact_phone'];
                           }
                         if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_outcome'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['app_outcome'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_outcome'];
                         }
                         if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_date_closed'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['app_date_closed'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['app_date_closed'];
                         }
                         if( $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_id'] != ""){
                            $ResumeUpdate[$key]['resume_id'] = $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_id'];
                         }

                         $ResumeUpdate[$key]['resume_id']=$Resume['id'][$key];
                        unset($ResumeInsert[$key]);
                      }
                     else{
                        $ResumeInsert[$key]['resume_id'] = $GetLastID;
                        $GetLastID++;
                    }

                $status=$this->Resume_model->ProcessData($idsToDelete,$ResumeUpdate,$user_id,$ResumeInsert,$imgInsert,$imgUpdate);
                redirect('Resume','refresh');   

        }
    }
?>
```

**Here the insert query (model)**

```
function ProcessData($tbl_resumeInsert){

      if(!empty($tbl_resumeInsert))

     {

             $this->insert_tbl_resume($user_id,$tbl_resumeInsert);
     }

}

function insert_tbl_resume($id,$arrtbl_resume)

{

       $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_resume', $arrtbl_resume); 

}
```

in above code,when im going to submit the form only first **`Foreach loop`**'s data can insert,when i print **`$ResumeInsert`**,it shows me only first foreach loop's data `foreach($this->input->post('Person_id') as $key =>$value )`
Rest foreach loop's data appears `NULL` in **DB**

please any help?
Thank You!

Comment: Can you put in your html too

Answer (score 0):

The function `$this->input->post('something')` is returning a value from the  `$_POST` array with a key of 'something'. If the key 'something' does not exist it returns NULL. (or FALSE in CI version < 3.0)

`$_POST` is an associative array and will have at most only one item with any given key. So the code

```
foreach($this->input->post('Person_id') as $key =>$value )
{
  ...
```

will only run once as there is only one `$_POST` array item with the key 'Person_id'.

If your form html has more than one field named 'Person_id' only the value from the last field will be posted to the server.

Comment: I've Only one field named 'Person_id' in my HTML..and ofcorse,if i print something like echo "xyz" in my second foreach loop (**foreach($this->input->post('emp_id') as $key =>$value ){**) then i can get "Xyz" in my Browser and also if i print **$Resume['employer_name'][$key];**, then i can get the value of **"Employer name"** but if i print **($ResumeInsert)**  , then im getting only first foreach loop's data

Comment: `foreach($this->input->post('emp_id') as $key =>$value )` is looping through the `$_POST` array. You get only the first because there is only one item in `$_POST` with the key "emp_id". If the _data type_ of the value stored at `$this->input->post('emp_id')` is an array, and you want to extract values from _that array_ then you should do `$data = $this->input->post('emp_id'); foreach($data as $key => $value){...` Because you have already captured the entire `$_POST` array in `$Resume` you could (should) simply use `foreach($Resume['emp_id'] as $key => $value){...`

Comment: It would be much easier to offer suggestions if you edited your question to include either the html of the `<form>` or an explanation of the structures of your inputs.